# Facebook API send private message from page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I need to send private message from my page (i am the admin) to user who already contacted my page

My reference on that this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

I am testing this feature via Facebook Graph Explorer 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Using version V2.9

Request:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "USER_ID"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

i replace the USER_ID with my id and access token of page i am admin of

But my response is:
    `{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) No matching user found",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 2018001,
    "fbtrace_id": "AeMT8VK2SbX"
  }
}`

I know it is required special permission `pages_messaging` so i am testing this feature using Facebook application `Graph API Explorer` not my application because it is not approved yet to use this permission

Any idea why i got this error ?

Comment: This endpoint is for messenger bots - you can not simply use it to send a message to a user without having an actual messenger bot.

Comment: Ok, do you have any starting point/link can send me as a tutorial

Comment: For what? Messenger Bots? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform But be aware that this is a rather complex issue.

Comment: Complex issue to implement this feature using messenger bots? Do you know any other way can implement this feature (send message from page to user)?

Comment: No, I meant Messenger Bots in itself are a rather complex feature, not one I would recommend to get into for a beginner(?). If you just want to reply to a message a user send to your page once, I you can still go via the conversations edge, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations first, and then https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/conversation/messages#publish

Comment: Very cool solution. thanks CBroe (Y). i see the only limitation on it that it is just reply not initiate as you said. Any other limitation you may know about it. like limitation to reply within certain time

Comment: And that you can only reply once ... after that, the user would have to reply back to your page first, before you can send another message. I don’t know of any time limits (as opposed to Messenger Bots, where there are several limitations on this.) But there is no way for you to message a user that has not initiated the communication from there end before, that would be the same for a messenger bot.

Comment: @CBroe i tried to send multiple message and it sent successfully. I think it is can be more than one reply